# Will my tf.keras based code work transparently with Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have lots of code and models developed in Keras, where "keras" is actually tf.keras from Tensorflow 1.12.  I wonder if I install Tensorflow 2.0, will my code just work as is without changes?

Comment: `tf.keras` is the preferred way to build models in TensorFlow 2.x. However, there are several differences between 1.x and 2.x that might require you to make changes to your code, see [Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate). However, the easiest thing would be to set up TensorFlow 2.x in a Python or Anaconda virtual environment and try to use your code there.

Comment: My thinking was that I might get away with almost no changes since I'm only using keras, outside of a few low level tf versions of numpy functions.  If TF2 follows the keras API, I'm unclear on what could break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code should work without any change.

Just remember that `tf.keras` is a specific implementation of the Keras API specification, but the high-level API is always the same.
There could be some differences between `tf.keras` and `keras`, but obly some *extra* method added to the base API, no removal or breaking changes.

Hence, if your code uses only the high-level API of Keras, without any extra-operation from the backend, then you can be sure that replacing `keras` with `tf.keras` won't break anything.